# Unable to route in the home page

Tags: angular, routes

I am unable to figure out on how the router-outlet works in `app.component.html`.

When I load my default page(http://localhost:4200), I want the `<app-homepage></app-homepage>` to load in the content section, which is loading fine, however when I try to navigate through my menus from the `<app-header></app-header>`, when the `router-outlet` gets called, the `<app-homepage>` component also loads and appends it in the below.

I want homepage component to load at default and then when any menu component is called it should load in the content section.

My code is as below:

```
    <section class="main" >
          <section class="head_bg">
          <div class="header-nav">
            <app-header></app-header>
          </div>
          </section>
          <section class="content_bg">
            <div class="content">
    <app-homepage></app-homepage>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section class="foot_bg">
          <div class="footer-nav" >
          <app-footer></app-footer>
          </div>
          </section>
    </section>
    
      
    <div class="example-button-row" >
    <a routerLink="/homepage" routerLinkActive="active" button mat-button color="warn">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active" button mat-button color="warn">About Us</a>
    <a routerLink="/gallery" routerLinkActive="active" button mat-button color="warn">Gallery</a>
    <a routerLink="/contactus" routerLinkActive="active" button mat-button color="warn">Contact Us</a>
    </div>

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LeftMenuComponent } from './left-menu/left-menu.component';
import { RightMenuComponent } from './right-menu/right-menu.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ContactusComponent} from './contactus/contactus.component';
import { GalleryComponent} from './gallery/gallery.component';
import { AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
 import {HomepageComponent} from './homepage/homepage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'left-menu', component: LeftMenuComponent },
{ path: 'right-menu', component: RightMenuComponent },
{ path: 'content', component: ContentComponent },
{ path: 'footer', component: FooterComponent },
{ path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent },
{ path: 'contactus', component: ContactusComponent },
{ path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent},
{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
{ path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
//export const routingComponents = [LeftMenuComponent,RightMenuComponent]
```

Comment: Add your route config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an empty route and remove the `app-component` from the html:

```
{ path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
```

Do not forget to update the links to the homepage, it is not "/homepage" anymore.

Comment: Thanks, i added the empty route, but i would like to load the homepage component in the content section on my default page (http://localhost:4200), and i would like to use content section as container for the components too. So once the main page loaded, it should show (header - content(hompage-component) - footer). Then when i choose gallery from the menu section it should load the gallery component in the content section by overwriting on homepage component.

Comment: I am quite new to the angular, so not sure on the terminologies , hope i was able to put across my issue correctly. Please bear with me.

Comment: @Hussain this is exactly what i mentioned. If you define the empty route for HomepageComponent, it is loaded if you path is empty. As soon as the path is changed the router outlet loads another page. The router loads the first fully match. What happened after defining the empty route?

Comment: thanks alot, that worked perfectly fine the way i wanted.

Comment: I had this also added earlier, post commenting this line { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }, it worked fine.